# How to set style for an application so all controls are shown in my application's color scheme

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I would like to set a style for an MDI WinForms application in .NET (mix of C# and VB.NET). I would like all panels and forms to be of a certain color. I would like textboxes to be of a certain color when readonly and of a different color when NOT readonly. I don't want to use defaults. Any pointers on how I can make this GLOBAL for any Form that is developed for this application? Am looking for a way so I don't have to do this logic in every form I create.

PREFERABLY: Don't want to switch to using any third-party tools. Would like to stick with just WinForms and standard .NET libraries.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one on Code Project which includes source and is even free for commercial use.

It lets you associate a StyleSheetManager to your WinForms App, letting you define styles in an XML file - like a WinForms equivilent to CSS.

e.g.

```
   <Style Name="FormType1">
        <Properties>
            <Property Name="BackColor" Value="White" />
            <Property Name="Text" Value="Personal information" />
            <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
        </Properties>
    </Style>
```

Link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14814/StylesSheetManager-A-CSS-like-component-for-WinFor

Comment: This looks interesting... Will take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 3rd party control set like DevExpress, that has a full skinning system for WinForms apps.  You can allow the user to select the theme they want and you can also use their tool to create your own skin to match the colors you want.

They also have very deep extended properties for Appearance on all controls.

If you want to stick with just pure out of the box WinForms, I would suggest you create a base form with a method that executes on load or init of the of the form (you might have to play with this for for the timing of the control layout).  This would inherit from this base form for all the rest in your application.  This method would loop through the controls collection of the form and then set your color properties of the various controls. It would have to be recursive to get controls in container controls.  This way it is contained in one place for your app so if you have to add new color features or control types then it is one place to go.  I would also look into suspending and resuming layout in case there are any performance issues.

Comment: We tried DevExpress but for a number of reasons which I don't want to delve into it didn't work out.

Comment: Great idea also and I was actually thinking the same until I realized there are already about 200 forms in this application right now. (To be honest this was my backup plan). I would just sit and go through all the forms and change the inherits from "Form" to "MyCustomForm"). Thank you.

Comment: @Denis I would think it would be a global search and replace just look for ' : Form' or a fully qualified version (or the Inherits if it is in VB.NET).  No matter I hope the solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "[Themer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20040/Using-Themer-To-Skin-Forms-and-Controls)" found at CodeProject.com.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this CodeProject needs a third-party software called Themer. I thought they give you the source code. So I guess this is probably not going to work either...

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options, including some 3rd party skinning tools.

However, Have you tried extending the controls and overriding the 'Paint' Event, setting the colours according to the readonly property?

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't really see extending all controls as an answer. There are just too many...

Answer (score 1):

One of the best components you could try is DevExpress which has a Control named `defaultlookandfeel` which is exactly what you want but don't forget it's not free.

[Devexpress DefaultLookAndFeel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressLookAndFeelDefaultLookAndFeeltopic)

Comment: We tried DevExpress but for a number of reasons which I don't want to delve into it didn't work out

Comment: If you describe your problem, maybe I should help you to figure it out.

Comment: I am not sure what is not clear... I would like to set custom colors for controls on all forms in this application based on some theme-like concept